# Can't publish android library to bintray

Tags: android, android-library, bintray

I'm literally going crazy trying to publish a library to bintray.
I followed the official guide, as well as several tutorials, but my library was never uploaded to bintray.
The library itself is working fine (at least in my tests).

Here is the build.gradle file of the library module.
I ran the commands

```
./gradlew install
```

and then

```
./gradlw bintrayUpload
```

Both of them ends with a "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", but in bintray website nothing appear.
What am I doing wrong?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
//apply plugin: 'java'


def siteUrl = 'https://github.com/stefanosiano/PowerfulImageView'      // Homepage URL of the library
def gitUrl = 'https://github.com/stefanosiano/PowerfulImageView.git'   // Git repository URL
def libDescription = 'Custom Android ImageView with several added features.'
def gitTag = '0.1.1'
def pkgName = 'powerful-image-view'
def libGroupId = "com.stefanosiano"                                          // Maven Group ID for the artifact
def libArtifactId = "powerful-image-view"                                          // Maven Group ID for the artifact
def libName = "Powerful Image View"                                          // Maven Group ID for the artifact
def libVersion = "0.1.1"// This is the library version used when deploying the artifact

group = libGroupId //bintray org/group name
version = libVersion //version

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName libVersion
        consumerProguardFiles 'piv-proguard-rules.txt'

    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
}






install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'
                groupId libGroupId
                artifactId libArtifactId

                // Add your description here
                name libName
                description libDescription
                url siteUrl

                // Set your license
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'MIT License'
                        url 'https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'stefanosiano'
                        name 'Stefano Siano'
                        email 'stefano.siano91@gmail.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl

                }
            }
        }
    }
}



version = libVersion

if (project.hasProperty("android")) { // Android libraries
    task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    }

    task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    }
} else { // Java libraries
    task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from sourceSets.main.allSource
    }
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}




// https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin
bintray {
    user = System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = System.getenv('BINTRAY_KEY')

    configurations = ['archives']

    // Package info for BinTray
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven-repo'
        // it is the name that appears in bintray when logged
        name = pkgName
        desc = libDescription
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ['MIT']
        publish = true
        publicDownloadNumbers = true
        version {
            name = libVersion
            desc = libDescription
            released = new Date()
            vcsTag = gitTag
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my project build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
// Plugin used to upload authenticated files to BinTray through Gradle
plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.7.3"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks for any help, because i'm trying from some day unsuccessfully :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for me the problem was that my Fedora lost my environment variables.
After exporting them again, everything worked fine.

I have my first library online! Yay!